# Let's name our chat room

Tags: discussion, chat

Let's get things rolling in making this site our own and name our [chat room.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21415/music-fans) Post your suggestions below and be sure to vote on your favorite.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Off the record

Answer (score 9):

## The Record Shop

---

A little outdated, but speaks to why most of us are here.

Comment: I personally think that this is ideal, it also implies a place in which music fans would come together to discuss.

Comment: Maybe something like "Vinyl Seating"?  Might be too obtuse.

Comment: I prefer a name that starts with 'music'.

Comment: @Avis check out my [answer](http://meta.musicfans.stackexchange.com/a/119/74) it starts with music

Answer (score 6):

## The Audience

Because we are fans of music..

Comment: Good thought.  Maybe we could tweak it to make it clearly about music?

Answer (score 3):

## Backstage

The place where fans usually meet the artists and discussions happen

Answer (score 1):

### The Listening Room

Where we listen and discuss.

Answer (score 0):

**The Juke Joint**

A bit more lively - a fun place to hang out.

Comment: Maybe "The Jukebox"?  "Juke Joint" sounds a bit strange to me.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Juke_joint

Comment: Ah, it's an existing term!  My bad.

Comment: Since the origins of the term are rooted in the days before the US Civil War, it's not surprising that it isn't widely remembered.

Comment: @MatthewRead The Jukebox can also be make into suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

### The Whistle Test

Reference to [The Old Grey Whistle Test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Old_Grey_Whistle_Test)

> According to presenter Bob Harris, the programme derived its name from a Tin Pan Alley phrase from years before. When they got the first pressing of a record they would play it to people they called the old greys - doormen in grey suits. The songs they could remember and whistle, having heard it just once or twice, had passed the old grey whistle test.

Answer (score -1):

## Music Motel

Based on [Holiday Music Motel](http://www.holidaymusicmotel.com/).

Answer (score -4):

### Woofers and Tweeters

Bellowing and shrieking.

Answer (score -5):

## Cassette deck

Where tapes meet mp3...

Answer (score -9):

## Gamma Scale

Maybe? Could be also "Major gamma" or... "Ascending gamma".

Comment: What is Gamma and how does it relate to music?

Comment: @Shev gamma scale...

Comment: Does this have something to do with a fan?

Comment: @Shev It relates to music...

Comment: I think the problem with this name that it neither relates to music fandom, nor discussing things.

Comment: it would make me think we were discussing computer monitors, not music. I've never heard the term in relation to audio in 35 years in the business.