# Is there something that needs to be done if the main chatroom was frozen?

Tags: discussion, chat

I have noticed that the main chatroom<sup>1</sup> has been [recently frozen](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/21415/2021/4/28). (As far as I can tell, this was the [first time this happened](https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=frozen&room=21415&user=-2))

This happens if a room had no messages for 14 days. The system always keep at least one room for the site open, but there are [other rooms associated with this site](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&sort=active&host=musicfans.stackexchange.com).

What (if anything) should be done?

- Maybe this is a sign that the main chatroom isn't really needed. After all it was frozen because there were no messages for some time. (And [some of the messages in this room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=frozen&room=21415) were posted just to prevent it from freezing.)
- If the room should be unfrozen, [this can be done by a moderator](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70198/how-do-i-unfreeze-a-frozen-chat-room/70201#70201). What is a good way to attract the attention of the mods to this issue?
- Some rooms [use a bot](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/382851/generic-bot?tab=recent) to be immune from freezing - the bot post a message in the room if there was no activity for some time. This is suitable if the community wants to keep some room indefinitely. Would this be a solution? If this is the preferred solution, can somebody set up such bot?

<sup>1</sup>By the [main chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/21415/2015/2/24) I mean the room which was includes the "welcome message" and was created at the creation of the sites. Of course, in all aspects (from the viewpoint of the Stack Exchange software), this room is the same as other rooms associated with the site. (The room is [called Off the record](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/21415?m=23133548#23133548). See also: [Let's name our chat room](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1).)

---

Here are some posts where you can find more details concerning frozen rooms:

- [Why is the main chat room frozen?](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/343)
- [Don't freeze a chatroom soon after a mod has unfrozen it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/130472)
- [Main chatroom for a SE site and chatroom pruning](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/226302)
- [Main chat room for a newer site still freezes due to inactivity](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/352769)
- A related feature request: [Exclude the main chat room from automatic freezing/deletion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/100519)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just unfroze the room. In general, if you point any mod to the room, they can unfreeze it that should be the first course of action. There's a lot of mods around SE so even if we're not on for a few days, someone should be able to help.

Rooms freeze due to lack of activities and bots alone I do no think can keep them open, so the best way to keep it from freezing is to keep posting in it.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond. I will clarify that I meant bot similar to [Generic Bot](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/382851/generic-bot?tab=recent) - that one keeps some rooms alive when they are inactive. I am aware that feeds - such as [Meta Bot](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/-339/meta-bot?tab=recent) -
are [not sufficient to prevent freezing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238911/do-messages-from-feeds-prevent-freezing-deleting-a-chat-room/238923#238923).

Comment: If I notice that this room is getting close to 14 days of inactivity, I'll post there something - I have done this [a few times in the past](https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=frozen&room=21415&user=11287)